# Checking user name against LDAP directory without password c# 4.5

Tags: c#-4.0, ldap

I'm working in C#.Net 4.5. I'm using below code to check whether a particular user belongs to the given AD group or not. But, it is not giving results, though I enter valid user details.

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry();
de.Path = "LDAP://xyz.com";
DirectorySearcher deSearch = new DirectorySearcher();
deSearch.SearchRoot = de;
string usr = "test1";
deSearch.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(anr={0}))", usr);
SearchResult result = deSearch.FindOne();
```

I have tried with below Filter criteria as well, but result is null. Please let me know what went wrong in my code.

1. deSearch.Filter ="(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sn="+usr+"))"
2. deSearch.Filter = "(uid=" + usr+ ")";
3. deSearch.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(racfid="+usr+"))"

Answer (score 0):

Try `userPrincipalName` like this:

```
deSearch.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName=" + usr  + "@*))";
deSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("userPrincipalName");
deSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");

SearchResult result = deSearch.FindOne();
```

Comment: In the last line, I think I should replace aDirSearcher with deSearch. right?

Comment: I've replaced aDirSearcher with deSearch and tried. still the result shows null value

Comment: Yeah `aDirSearcher`  = `deSearch`. I edited my answer. What exactly is your `usr` variable? `test1` is a windows login? You can try replacing `userPrincipalName=` with `cn=`

Comment: Sorry, Peska. its not working after replacing userPrincipalName with cn also